# Custom Component support in TapestryTools Tapestry5

Tags: eclipse-plugin, custom-component, tapestry

I have used [tapestryTools](http://code.google.com/p/tapestrytools/) in Eclipse-Indigo. it is working fine for me. I would like to discuss one points here.

1.In the custom component i can see only those components which are inside the Project. but in my case i have some jar files which also contain the tapestry components and i would like to see those components in the palette. is there any way through which i can see those components which are inside the jar. and that jar is included in the project.

Regards,
Mahendra